# Every 33-length subsequence of $1,2,\dotsc,122$ contains a three term arithmetic progression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory

Is it possible to prove that every 33-length subsequence of the sequence $1,2,3,\dotsc,122$ contains a three term arithmetic progression?

Maybe I should post it on mathoverflow

Comment: When you say "contains," does that mean three consecutive terms of the subsequence, or can you pick any three elements from the sub-sequence? (I don't think it is true for three consecutive terms.)

Comment: pick three elements from the sub-sequence.   Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd like to point out that the $32$-term sequence $1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 13, 14, 28, 29, 31, 32, 37, 38, 40, 41, 82, 83, 85, 86, 91, 92, 94, 95, 109, 110, 112, 113, 118, 119, 121, 122$ contains no $3$-term arithmetic progression.

Comment: I think this is the same question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494206/how-prove-this-will-be-a-length-of-3-arithmetic-progression but this one is clearer formulated

Comment: Gerry Myerson's comment at [494206](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494206/) points out that ["Sequences Containing No 3-Term Arithmetic Progressions"](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v19i2p15), published 2012 in the *Electronic Journal of Combinatorics*, claims to solve this problem, "with a use of computer", for the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me add some comments to Alexander Walker's nice answer:

The problem is first studied in the paper

> Paul Erdős, and Paul Turán. [*On some sequences of integers*](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1936-05.pdf), J. London Math. Soc., **11 (4)**, (1936), 261--264. [MR1574918](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1574918), Zentralblatt [JFM 62.1126.01](http://zbmath.org/?q=an:62.1126.01).

There $r(n)$ is defined as the length of the largest sequence of elements from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with no three terms in arithmetic progression. A conjecture by Szekeres is mentioned that $$r\left(\frac12(3^k+1)\right)=2^k.$$
This can be verified more or less directly for $k\le 4$. Note that for $k=5$ it gives the result you asked for. The paper mentions that $\displaystyle r\left(\frac12(3^k+1)\right)\ge 2^k$ is easy to see: Given $k$, let $A$ be the set of integers of the form $u+1$ with $\displaystyle 0\le u\le \frac12(3^k-1)$ and such that the ternary expansion of $u$ has no twos. We then see that $A$ has size $2^k$ and no three terms are in arithmetic progression. For $k=5$, so $N=122$, the resulting set $A$ has size $32$ and equals
 $$\begin{array}{c}\{1,2,4,5,10,11,13,14,28,29,31,32,37,38,40,41,82,83,85,86,91,92,94,95,109,110,\\  112,113,118,119,121,122\}.\end{array} $$
This means that $33$ cannot be replaced with a smaller number.

The paper (also mentioned in the comments)

> Janusz Dybizbański. [*Sequences Containing No 3-Term Arithmetic Progressions*](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v19i2p15/pdf),  Electron. J. Combin., **19 (2)**, (2012), paper 15, 5 pp. [MR2928630](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2928630),

establishes a result that for the first time verifies that Szekeres conjecture holds for $k=5$. The argument uses a computer search, and no computer-free combinatorial approach seems known at the moment.

As Walker pointed out in a comment, it should be remarked that Szekeres's conjecture is actually *false*. The point is that we now have a good understanding for the asymptotic behavior of the function $r$, that clashes with what the conjecture predicts. Specifically, we know that for any $\epsilon>0$, there are constants $c,C>0$ such that for $N$ large enough, we have 
 $$ cN^{1-\epsilon}<r(N)<CN^{1-\epsilon}. $$ 
For example, in

> Tom Sanders. *On Roth's theorem on progressions*, Ann. of Math. (2), **174 (1)**, (2011), 619-636. [MR2811612 (2012f:11019)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2811612),

it is shown that for some $C$, $$r(N)<C\frac{(\log\log N)^5}{\log N}N,$$
while (more relevant for our current discussion), in

> Felix Adalbert Behrend. *On sets of integers which contain no three terms in arithmetical progression*, Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U. S. A., **32**, (1946), 331–332. [MR0018694 (8,317d)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=18694),

it is shown that for some $c$, $$ r(N)>N^{1-\frac{c}{\sqrt{\log N}}}. $$
For $N$ large, this inequality clashes with the value predicted by Szekeres conjecture, that gives that $r(N)\le C'N^{\log_32}$ for $N$ of the form $\displaystyle\frac12(3^k+1)$.

(Actually, the first disproof of Szekeres's conjecture is much older than the above suggests: In

> Raphaël Salem, and Donald C. Spencer. [*On sets of integers which contain no three terms in arithmetical progression*](http://www.pnas.org/content/28/12/561.full.pdf+html), Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A., **28 (12)**, (1942), 561–563. [MR0007405 (4,131e)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=7405),

it is shown that for any $\epsilon>0$, $$ r(n)\ge n^{1-\frac{1+\epsilon}{\log\log n}}$$ for all $n$ large enough.)

As Walker further points out in the comments, Jaroslaw Wroblewski has organized a search for sets without $3$-term arithmetic progressions, which in particular has found an example of length $128$ in $\{1,2,\dots,1092\}$, hence refuting Szekeres conjecture for $k=7$. This, and the other results of their search, can be seen on [this page](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~jwr/non-ave/DATABASE.TXT) (search for $a(128)$). It appears that whether the conjecture holds for $k=6$ is still open.

For a nice survey of the known results on sets without three term arithmetic progressions, see

> William Gasarch, James Glenn, and Clyde P. Kruskal. [*Finding Large Sets Without Arithmetic Progressions of Length Three: An Empirical View and Survey. II*](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/3apsurvey.pdf), 2010, preprint.

Comment: The conjecture of Szekeres is false in general, since $r(k)$ is bounded below by $O(r^{1-\epsilon})$, whereas the conjecture would imply that $\liminf r(k)/k^{\log_3 2}$ bounded.  I'm not sure if it's known when Szekeres first fails.

Comment: Yes, I should add something about it. Thanks, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: I did some more snooping, and it appears that Wroblewski's team has found a $128$-term $3$-free set contained in $[1,1092]$.  So Szekere's conjecture fails for $k=7$.  It seems that $k=6$ is the sole outstanding case.

Comment: Hehe. Thanks. I'll add a new remark.

Answer (score 6):

This is hardly an answer, but I'd like to direct you to [OEIS A065825.](http://oeis.org/A065825)

This sequence, beginning

$$S_3=\{1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 11, 13, 14, 20, 24, 26, 30, 32, 36, 40, 41, 51, 54, 58, 63, 71, 74, 82, 84, 92, 95, 100, 104, 111, 114, 121, 122, 137, 145, 150, 157, 163, 165, 169, 174, 194\}$$
gives for its $n$th term the minimum $k$ such that $[1,k]$ that has an $n$-term subset that avoids $3$-term arithmetic progressions (typically called a $3$-free set).  Since the $32$ term of this sequence is $122$ and the $33$rd is $137$, it follows that no $33$ term sequence in $[1,122]$ is $3$-free.  Not much is known about the growth of this sequence, and I would not be surprised if the sequence above had been found by brute force calculations.

It was at one point conjectured that the sequence $G_3=\{1,2,4,5,10,\ldots\}$ (i.e. the sequence obtained by always appending the smallest element that retains $3$-freeness) would yield competitive bounds to $S_3$ infinitely often. This was been disproved by work of F. Behrend in 1946, who crafted examples of $3$-free sets of length $n$ that fit in the interval $n^{1+\epsilon}$ (for fixed $\epsilon >0$ and sufficiently large $n$).  In contrast, we can prove that the "greedy" version of this packing requires space like
$$n^{\log_2 3},$$
by recognizing it as the set of integers whose base $3$ representation omits the digit $2$, increased by $1$.