# 3-term arithmetic progression in a set of integers

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle, arithmetic-progressions

Choose a set S consisting of $\frac{n+1}{2}$ numbers from the first $n$ natural numbers($1,2,3,...,n$) ($n\geq 2017$, $n$ is odd). Prove that there must be three numbers in S which are a 3-term arithmetic progression.

I am thinking of using recursion but I find the condition $n \geq 2017$ quite weird. Some smaller cases like $n=7$ or $n=9$ is not true (1,2,4,5) (1,2,6,7,9).

Comment: $(1,4,7)$ is a three term arithmetic progression for $n=9$.

Comment: I have edited. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **answer from a reputable source**.

In 1936 Erdős and Turán [ET] for a natural number $n$ defined $r(n)$ as the largest size of a subset of $\{1,\dots, n\}$ without three-term arithmetic progressions. Bounds from $r(n)$ are well-studied, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508963/every-33-length-subsequence-of-1-2-dotsc-122-contains-a-three-term-arithmetic) thread. Then your question is to show that $r(2n+1)\le n$ if $n\ge 1008$. Already the first theorem from [ET] stating that $r(2n)\le n$ if $n\ge 8$ provides almost the required bound. The needed improvement follows from obvious Inequality (3), stating $r(m+n)\le r(m)+r(n)$ and the equality $r(17)=8$, proved on the next page. It follows that $r(2n+1)\le n$ if $n\ge 25$. In fact, the values of $r(n)$ presented at the same page show that $r(2n+1)\le n$ if $n\ge 17$.

*References*

[ET] Paul Erdős, Paul Turán. [*On some sequences of integers*](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1936-05.pdf), J. London Math. Soc., **11**:4, (1936), 261–264. [MR1574918](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1574918), Zentralblatt [JFM 62.1126.01](http://zbmath.org/?q=an:62.1126.01).

Comment: they call $r(m+n) \le r(m)+r(n)$ an equality?

Comment: +1 for first sentence

Answer (score 5):

Write $x$ for an element fo $S$ and $o$ for a non-element. Then any (infinite) sequence of $x$'s and $o$'s can be obtained by concatenating the following building blocks:

$$o, xo, xxoo, xxoxooo, \color{red}xxo\color{red}xoo\color{red}x, 
x\color{red}xo\color{red}xo\color{red}x, xxoxxoooo, \color{red}xxox\color{red}xooo\color{red}x, x\color{red}xox\color{red}xoo\color{red}x, \color{red}xxo\color{red}xxo\color{red}x, xxo\color{red}{xxx}, \color{red}{xxx}$$
as can be read off the following tree:

[image]

If we drop those leading to an arithmetc progression (cf. read markings) we are only left with

$$A_1= o, A_2=xo, A_3=xxoo, A_4=xxoxooo, A_5=xxoxxoooo.$$

If we use these to write down the pattern corresonding to $S$, we may produce up to four extra $o$'s. By possibly appending $A_1$, we end up with $n+4$ symbols, the last four being $o$. If $n_i$ is the number of occurences of block $A_i$, we obtain the folowing equations:
$$ n_1+2n_2+4n_3+7n_4+9n_5=n+4$$
$$ n_2+2n_3+3n_4+4n_5=|S|$$
We conclude 
$$ 2|S|=n+4-n_1-n_4-n_5.$$
In other words, we want to show 
$$\tag{!}n_1+n_4+n_5\ge 4.$$
For how long a sequence can we work with only $A_2$ and $A_3$? 
All sequences of three blocks $A_2$ or $A_3$ lead to arithmetic progressions:

- $A_2A_2A_2=\color{red}xo\color{red}xo\color{red}xo$
- $A_2A_2A_3=\color{red}xo\color{red}xo\color{red}xxoo$
- $A_3A_3A_2=\color{red}xxoo\color{red}xxoo\color{red}xo$
- $A_3A_3A_3=\color{red}xxoo\color{red}xxoo\color{red}xxoo$
- $A_2A_3A_2=\color{red}xox\color{red}xoo\color{red}xo$
- $A_2A_3A_3=\color{red}xox\color{red}xoo\color{red}xxoo$
- $A_3A_2A_2= x\color{red}xoo\color{red}xox\color{red}o$
- $A_3A_2A_3= x\color{red}xoo\color{red}xox\color{red}xoo$

We conclude that out of three consecutive blocks, at most two are $A_2$ or $A_3$.
Then 
$$n_2+n_3\le \left\lceil\frac{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5}{3}\right\rceil $$
or
$$2(n_2+n_3)\le n_1+n_4+n_5+2.$$
Now if $n_1+n_4+n_5\le 3$, this gives us $n_2+n_3\le 2$ and so 
$$ n=n_1+2n_2+4n_3+7n_4+9n_5-4\le 4(n_2+n_3)+9(n_1+n_4+n_5)-4\le 31.$$
Hence for any $n>31$, we have $(!)$ and thererfore 
$$ |S|\le\frac n2.$$

Comment: Your proof can be simplified: we need $(n+1)/2$ $x$'s, thus *more* $x$'s than $o$'s. None of your $A_1,\dots,A_5$ contains *more* $x$'s than $o$'s, so $S$ must contain a sequence which is not entirely a concatenation of instances of $A_1,\dots,A_5$, so $S$ must contain an AP of at least 3 terms.